# Query string restriction and redirection?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, query-string, querystringparameter

Is it possible to restrict my websites query string parameters to those I allocate. In doing so can I redirect any URLs with query string parameters not found on my approved list to my 404 page?

For example I want only '?s=' and '?p=' to be allowed as query string parameters, therefore if `www.mysite.com/?x=whatever` is accessed the site will redirect that user my 404 page - if `www.mysite.com/?s=whatever` then my site will display the appropriate content.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is this supposed to be an approach to security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of allowed query string parameters like this:

```
$allowed_parameters = array( 's', 'q' );
```

If the $_GET array contains any key other than those allowed, redirect the user:

```
foreach ( $_GET as $key => value ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $key, $allowed_parameters ) ) {
        header( "Location: http://www.mysite.com/error404.html" );
        exit;
   }
}
```

Use `exit` to stop processing immediately. Without it, the redirect will happen after all remaining array keys are processed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with .htaccess, you can make something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(s=(.*)|404.html)
RewriteRule .* 404.html [R=404,L]
```

Also, you must be generating pages for ?s= dynamically, so make sure to make an exception for index.php (or the script you are using):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^s=(.*)|404.html|index.php)
RewriteRule .* 404.html [R=404,L]
```

Haven't tested, but this should work.

If you want to do it with PHP, then simply check the $_GET variable and redirect or display the 404 page if there's no ?s=:

```
if (!(isset($_GET['s'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    header('Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, private');
    readfile('404.html');
    exit;
}
```

You get the point.

Comment: This won't actually work as %{REQUEST_URI} does **not** include the query string: from that Apache website `REQUEST_URI The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.`

Answer (score 1):

Just check the `$_GET` and find if there are disallowed parameters then redirect to your 404 page.

Comment: To elaborate: `<?php foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) { if ($k != 's' && $k != 'p') { header("Location: 404.html", true, 404); } }`. Alternatively you can also do it with mod_rewrite and htaccess.

Comment: @Col: if the array is empty it means that there's no parameters passed, so it should be considered a valid request (or so I see it).

Comment: @Col: Something like this? http://codepad.org/3MD9Ine5 // If you're referring to the fact that I'm assuming $_GET as an array, I believe it is by default.

Comment: @andre ah yes it works, my bad. However I  consider looping over Get a bit redundant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4441/discussion-between-andre-and-col-shrapnel)

Answer (score 1):

On Apache you could use mod_rewrite... something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^x=(allowed_values_of_x)$
RewriteRule ^path/in/uri$ /redirect/to/file?withquery=%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^x=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^path/in/uri$ /redirect/to/404?withquery=%1 [R=404,L]
```

If values of `x` are valid it'll redirect to a file with the valid `x` parameter, otherwise it should redirect to a 404 handler with the invalid `x` parameter (so you can do something fancy with it if you wish).

Look at Apache mod_rewrite conditionals at:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond